# jQuery code doesn't work at the page - buttons are not affected by the code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning jQuery on coursera now and following the code from the video, but it doesn't work:

1. the carousel elements should stop when press on button, which has "stop" symbol
2. of button should change to "play"-symbol
3. after pressing the button "play", it should start to play.

What i have: button doesn't change, it is "stop"-button, it just throws to another carousel-item instead of stopping carousel. The problem appears both in Chrome and in Firefox

What i've tried:

1. i tried to remove `data-ride="carousel"` after pressing the button (someone adviced on Coursera):

> The data-ride="carousel" attribute is used to mark a carousel as animating starting at page load. It cannot be used in combination with (redundant and unnecessary) explicit JavaScript initialization of the same carousel. Source: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#via-data-attributes. So, for the div with id "my-carousel", you will need to remove the attribute data-ride="carousel" .

2. i also tried to add cycle and pause to #mycarousel `$('#mycarousel').carousel({ interval: 2000,cycle: true, pause: "null" });`, like another person adviced on Coursera:

> I think it's the way carousel works by default. For the hovering problem I found that you can specify that you want no pause :
> $('#mycarousel').carousel({ interval: 2000,
> cycle: true,
> pause: "null" });

3. i've also tried to see what's goind on on console, after clicking (thanks Danimal for that piece of advice!), but it's empty, nothing happens.
4. i've also tried to link to jquery.min.js instead of jquery.slim.min.js (thanks Alon Eitan and  freedomn-m for a piece of advise!), but for now, nothing has changed.
5. i've also tried to move the whole code inside `$(document).ready(function() {});` (thanks ADyson!)

So, it seems like the problem is that jQuery code is not visible at all - after commenting the whole code, nothing changes on the page, button acts the same.

There are also a lot of open issues on course's forum, so it seems like it's not only my problem. I couldn't find any information on the Internet which would help to solve this issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mycarousel').carousel({
    interval: 2000,
    cycle: true,
    pause: "null"
  });
  $("#carouselButton").click(function() {
    if ($("#carouselButton").children("span").hasClass('fa-pause')) {
      $("#mycarousel").carousel('pause');
      $("#carouselButton").children("span").removeClass('fa-pause');
      $("#carouselButton").children("span").addClass('fa-play');
      $('#carouselButton').attr('data-ride', 'carousel');
    } else if ($("#carouselButton").children("span").hasClass('fa-play')) {
      $("#mycarousel").carousel('cycle');
      $("#carouselButton").children("span").removeClass('fa-play');
      $("#carouselButton").children("span").addClass('fa-pause');
      $('#carouselButton').removeAttr('data-ride');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.carousel {
  background: #512DA8;
}

.carousel-item {
  height: 100px;
}

.carousel-item img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 200px;
}

#carouselButton {
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-content">
    <div class="col">
      <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <h2>Uthappizza</h2>
            <!-- some code here -->
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <h2>About Us</h2>
            <!-- some code here -->
          </div>

          <div class="carousel-item">
            <h2>Great Buffet</h2>
            <!-- some code here -->
          </div>
        </div>

        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
        </a>
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="carouselButton">
                <span id="carousel-button-icon" class="fa fa-pause"></span>
              </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- scripts before closing body tag -->
  <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? and what is the problem with what you have so far?

Comment: I made a you a snippet. Please replace your dist jquery and bootstrap with relevant CDN versions

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I'm afraid you haven't described the problem you're observing.  Help us to help you by providing information about the problem and what you're attempting to solve.  For tips and information on asking a question, please read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: " this issue " ...so what _is_ the issue? Apart from "doesn't work" which could mean 1000 things and is therefore no use at all as a description, you haven't explained what the code is actually doing, or what you expected it to do instead. You haven't mentioned any error messages, or any debugging you've tried. It's much harder for us to help when you don't clearly describe the problem. You need to give us enough info to know where to start looking. We are not mind-readers.

Comment: Do you know what error you are getting?  In browsers like FF and Chrome you can hit F12 and look at the console log of the page. This is usually the first step in debugging your Javascript/jquery

Comment: You're using the `.slim` version of jquery - do you know the difference?  Remove the `.slim` from your jquery link and try again.  `<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>`  (might need to download/install the "normal" jquery though)

Comment: Just by looking at `$('#mycarousel').carousel` and `jquery.slim.min.js` - I think that you need to load the regular jQuery and not the slim because it doesn't support animation

Comment: Did you try putting `$('#mycarousel').carousel({
  interval: 2000,
  cycle: true,
  pause: "null"
});` inside the `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` area as well? Otherwise, that code will be executed before the HTML has finished loading, and therefore might (depending where the script is positioned in your real page) be executed before the mycarousel HTML element actually exists in the DOM, meaning that jQuery will be unable to find it, and therefore unable to attach the carousel functionality to it. This kind of thing will fail silently without an error.

Comment: "it is "stop"-button"...in your code you don't appear to have a stop button, only a pause button

Comment: Rather than simply pasting version names of your libraries can you please update the Snippet to link to CDN copies of those libraries online (and any CSS etc which is needed), so that the snippet would be runnable and would demonstrate your problem? That is the point of having a code snippet in the question.

Comment: ok thanks. so if you use your browser's element inspector, you can see that the total space occupied by the `>` button of the carousel overlays your custom "pause" button (it has a lot of padding) and has a higher z-index, so I think your button is probably never even receiving the click event. You could verify it by adding some console logging or using the debugger. You could possibly resolve this by giving the pause button a higher z-index (z-index of the `>` button is 1, so anything higher than that might work.

Comment: I made a runnable snippet and the same problem with button is here

Comment: P.S. It's even more obvious that's the problem if you watch carefully - whenever you _appear_ to be clicking on the pause button, if you notice it actually immediately moves the carousel to the next item - because in reality it's activating the "next" button whose (invisible) padding area is over the top of the pause button.

Comment: So I think it's just a `z-index` issue on the pause button. Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/fmx2gcro/) how you expect it to work?

Comment: Use this css #carouselButton {z-index: 9999999;} next button taking space.

Comment: @AlonEitan thank you, that helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use your browser's element inspector, you can see that the total space occupied by the `>` button of the carousel overlays your custom "pause" button (it has a lot of padding) and has a higher [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index), so your button is never even receiving the click event,. You could verify it by adding some console logging or using the debugger.

You can resolve this by giving the pause button a higher z-index (z-index of the `>` button is 1, so anything higher than that will work), so that it is considered to be "above" the `>` button in the page's stacking context.

```
#carouselButton {
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2; //set z-index
}
```